# cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to get a specific cell from a table view so I can change it's label and stop the activity indicator.

The problem I'm having is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns nil.

My table view has only 1 row.

Code :

```
- (id) initWithNibName: (NSString*) nibNameOrNil bundle: (NSBundle*) nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle: nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) 
    {
        numberOfRows = 1;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section
{
    return numberOfRows;
}

-(void) stopCellIndicator
{

    LiveUserFeedCell* cell = (LiveUserFeedCell*)[self.liveFeed cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];  
    [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    cell.middleLabel.text = @"N/a";
}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UserFeedCell";


    LiveUserFeedCell *cell = (LiveUserFeedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LiveUserFeedCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (LiveUserFeedCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell.imgView setImage:[TUNinePatchCache imageOfSize:cell.imgView.frame.size forNinePatchNamed:@"bg_home_newsfeed_normal"]];


    if (shouldDisplayLoading == NO)
    {
        NSArray* songs = homeScreen.recentPlaybacks.songs;
        TWSong* song = [songs objectAtIndex:index];
        cell.middleLabel.text = @"";
        [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:14];                       

        NSString* kText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<b>%@</b> is listening to %@ by %@",song.user,song.title,song.artist];

        for(int i = 14; i > 0; i=i-1)
        {
            // Set the new font size.
            font = [font fontWithSize:i];
            // You can log the size you're trying: NSLog(@"Trying size: %u", i);

            /* This step is important: We make a constraint box 
             using only the fixed WIDTH of the UILabel. The height will
             be checked later. */ 
            CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(cell.isWatching.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

            // This step checks how tall the label would be with the desired font.
            CGSize labelSize = [kText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

            /* Here is where you use the height requirement!
             Set the value in the if statement to the height of your UILabel
             If the label fits into your required height, it will break the loop
             and use that font size. */
            if(labelSize.height <= cell.isWatching.frame.size.height)
                break;
        }



        cell.isWatching.font = font;
        cell.isWatching.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:kText lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];
        cell.isWatching.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        ++index;
        if (index == [songs count])
            index=0;

    }
    else
    {       
        [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

However, if I do something like this, I do get a valid cell:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                       [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                       nil];

numberOfRows = 0;
[self.liveFeed deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];


numberOfRows = 1;
[self.liveFeed insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

LiveUserFeedCell* cell = (LiveUserFeedCell*)[self.liveFeed cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];  
[cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
cell.middleLabel.text = @"N/a";
```

Any idea how to fix this? (Maybe the default first cell isn't in row 0 section 0?)

Comment: I can't see where you are overriding cellForRowAtIndex. As long as you don't, there won't be any cells.

Comment: Added more code.. take a look now. thx

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that the tableView was not configured yet when I queried the the cell.

Comment: What do you mean configured? How do you configure it?

Comment: Move the two levers on the back in upright position. Then push the start button, it's simple.

Answer (score 39):

It is worth mentioning that cellForRowAtIndexPath: will also return nil if the cell is not visible.

This can especially be an issue when threading...

Comment: How do you deal with this? I need a reference to the cell, when another VC is active.

Comment: What do you mean by "another VC"? Another VC(B) being active does not not affect cells in a different VC(A). This refers to cells within the 1 VC, and that: You will not get a reference to a cell if it's not active because it does not exist. VC recycle a few cell objects and reuses them.

Comment: Does it make sense to keep a copy of the cell and use it where its required ?

Comment: No, generally you do not need to keep direct references to cell objects, cell objects are reused constantly and managed by the Table object. Cell objects represent different items from your data source at any given time. If the cell is not visible, you do not need to do anything to it as it does not exist. Generally trying to access a cell that is out of view is an error.

Comment: Thanks, this is very important information, saved my day.

Answer (score 15):

I was having `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returning nil and the cause of it for me was that I was calling it in methods where the UITableView must not have been fully initialised and filled. Once I'd moved my call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` into `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` then my cell was returned correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue, cellForRowAtIndexPath returning nil, and for rather silly reasons. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I called a method which called method which calls `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`. (Was reusing existing code, and moving some logic downstream.)

As it turns out, the cell isn't yet available for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to return. You either need to do all your business modifying the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or, I guess, pass the `*cell` along.

Answer (score 3):

I got very similar condition with you, but I solved this problem by calling "super" function rather than self.tableView. I don't know why but it works at least. Maybe you can try.

```
[super tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Comment: BTW, my table is a static table, it may differ from your condition.

Comment: According to apple, from iOS 11, you have to prevent using tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: method otherwise it will crash your app.

Comment: @VineetAshtekar What? I can't find this information anywhere. Can you show any reference confirming this information?

Comment: Hi @VineetAshtekar, it would be better if you can provide a reference. Also, my answer was published on 2015 which iOS 11 wasn't released. Could you advice whether my answer is deprecated so that I'll edit it?

Answer (score 1):

you have solved the question though I have faced similar situation so what I have done I am showing you :

```
NSArray *cells = [contactsTable visibleCells];

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    NSIndexPath *path = [param objectAtIndex:1];
    for (UITableViewCell *aCell in cells) {
        NSIndexPath *aPath = [contactsTable indexPathForCell:aCell];

        if ([aPath isEqual:path]) {
            cell = aCell;
        }
    }
```

weird but works good after hours of trial & error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
[self.livFeed beginUpdates];   
LiveUserFeedCell* cell = (LiveUserFeedCell*)[self.liveFeed cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];  
[cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
cell.middleLabel.text = @"N/a";
[self.liveFeed endUpdates];
```

[Apple UITableView doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: how is getting cellForRowAtIndexPath within beginUpdates and endUpdates helping to make sure cell is not nil ?