# Last cell lost in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is something puzzling, or there is something obvious I am not seeing.

I am working with a table view (`UITableView`) and the code follows:

```
print("Number of row = \(tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0))")

for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) {
    print("Row = \(row)")

    if let _ = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)) {
        // All is OK.
    } else {print("THIS SHOULD NO HAPPEN!!")}
}
```

Here is what I get in the debugger window:

```
Number of row = 5
Row = 0
Row = 1
Row = 2
Row = 3
Row = 4
THIS SHOULD NO HAPPEN!!
(lldb)
```

My question is: Why do I get the message?: THIS SHOULD NO HAPPEN!!

There should be a cell on the last row. What is going wrong?

Comment: Because that cell is not visible. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232849/cellforrowatindexpath-returns-nil

Comment: The last cell is visible, I checked. Unless you mean currently visible on the screen? I will take a look at the post you mention.

Comment: Yes, I meant "visible on screen". Because it cannot display all cells of the table, it just displays items which visible on screen to user, and then load other cells when you scroll.

Comment: Indeed I realized after reading that you are right. I just did not remember of this fact. But my problem comes back to "how can I enumerate all the cells" (to reset their internal state for instance) independently of the fact they are visible or not?

Comment: You should not enumerate all the cells. If you want to change internal state, you should change it when it will be loaded (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)

Answer (score 0):

Is the last cell for which you are getting "THIS SHOULD NO HAPPEN!!" message is not visible? cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil if cell is not visible or index path is out of range.